# How to format Json to not nest associations with ActiveModel::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, serialization, active-model-serializers

I'm using ActiveModel::Serializer in a rails application to format my model data as a json response, but I would like to change the formatting so that the associations of my main model are not nested. I tried setting root: false and that doesn't work

##### Expected behavior vs actual behavior

I have a model `Account` with an association `belongs_to :account_status`
and I was able to add this association in the `AccountSerializer` to get that associated data just fine. But do to my api contract requirements, I need the json to be formatted without the association nesting.

So I'm getting this:

```yaml
{
   "account_id": 1
   <other account info>
   ...
   "account_status": {
      "status_code": 1
      "desc": "status description"
      ....
   }
}
```

But I want this:

```yaml
{
   "account_id": 1
   <other account info>
   ...
   "account_status_status_code": 1
   "account_status_desc": "status description"
   ....
}
```

##### Model + Serializer code

**How can I achieve the expected behavior without writing each `account_status` field as an individual attribute in the `AccountSerializer` ??**

Controller

```rb
class AccountsController < ActionController::API
  def show
    account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
    render json: account
  end
end
```

Model

```rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :account_id

  belongs_to :account_status, foreign_key: :account_status_code, inverse_of: :accounts

  validates :account_status_code, presence: true
end
```

Serializer

```rb
class AccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes(*Account.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym))

  belongs_to :account_status, 
             foreign_key: :account_status_code,
             inverse_of: :accounts
end
```

##### Environment

OS Type & Version: macOS Catalina v 10.15.7
*Rails 6.1.4*:

ActiveModelSerializers Version *0.10.0*:

Output of `ruby -e "puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION"`:
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-darwin19]

Comment: `validates :account_status_code, presence: true` is superflous since `belongs_to` associations are non-optional by default in Rails 5.1+. It will result in two validations errors which is most likely not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

you could replace `belongs_to :account_status,...` by below code

```rb
class AccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes(*Account.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym))
  
  AccountStatus.attribute_names.each do |attr_name|
    key = "account_status_#{attr_name}"
    define_method(key) do
     # i checked and see that `object.account_status` just call one time
     object.account_status.send(attr_name)
    end
    attribute key.to_sym   
  end
end
```

Comment: `attribute` takes an optional block so you could skip the step of creating methods. https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/active_model_serializers/0.10.1/ActiveModel/Serializer/Attribute

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an assocation in your serializer you can [setup delegation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) in your model:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  delegate :desc, ..., 
    to: :account_status,
    prefix: true
end
```

This will create a `account_status_desc` method which you can simply call from your serializer:

```
class AccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes(
    :foo, 
    :bar, 
    :baz,
    :account_status_code, # this is already a attribute of Account
    :account_status_desc
    # ...
  )
end
```

Another way of doing this is by simply adding methods to your serializer:

```
class AccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :foo

  def foo
    object.bar.do_something
  end
end
```

This is a good alternative when the result of serialization does not align with the internal representation in the model.

Comment: I would consider `*Account.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym)` to be a potential security problem. While convenient it risks exposing data that should not be exposed. Just like with parameter whitelisting you should just use an explicit whitelist of what the client should be able to access instead of dangerous magic.